# What is react router onEnter nextPathname doing?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

in below code, if not auth then redirect to login with `replace pathname` but what is `state` doing ?

EDITED
onEnter doesn't redirect user to the same location

login.js

```
    login() {

/*      ref.authWithOAuthPopup(this.props.provider, (error, authData) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Authentication Failed!", error);
            } else {
                console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
                console.log(this.state) // return null here
            }
        }) */
    }
```

authenticated.js

```
import Firebase from 'firebase';
import GLOBAL from './global.js';

var ref = new Firebase(GLOBAL.FIREBASE_URL);

export function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {

    ref.onAuth((authData) => {
        if ( !authData ) {
            replace ({
                pathname: '/login',
                state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

route.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, hashHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import Layout from './pages/Layout';
import Purchased from './pages/Purchased';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Profile from './pages/Profile';
import PurchasedItemDetail from './pages/PurchasedItemDetail';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import { requireAuth } from './utils/authenticated';

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home} onEnter={requireAuth} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/purchased" component={Purchased} onEnter={requireAuth} />
        <Route path="/purchased/:purchasedItemID" component={PurchasedItemDetail} onEnter={requireAuth} />
        <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} onEnter={requireAuth} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nextState parameter in this function is a [Router State object](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/b06d1db7864ba16e36dc7bdae40e18ed86d23907/docs/Glossary.md#routerstate) that represents what the next state of the application the user is going to enter into. So when you pass `state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }` you are telling the route handler you want this data to be sent along. In this case its a redirect route basically. Aka after login redirect them to some location.

Comment: i don't get it. should I call `this.state.nextPathname` in my login callback?

Comment: I'd have to see how that is being used.

Comment: my /login and <Route onEnter> are in different files

Comment: when you finish the login and you have a success you need to then redirect to the path they were trying to go to. not sure Im understanding what the issue is?

Comment: as you said _after login redirect them to some location._  Assume an user come to /profile page then i check `if Auth` in `<Router onEnter>` if not auth then i redirect it to /login. My issue here, the user login at /login page, it doesn't redirect them to the same location which is /profile

Comment: yea because you need to dispatch(pushPath(your location here))

Comment: You mean reflux or redux?  can I do this without them ?

Comment: Ok , so this is not what your question was originally. lets just clear some stuff up, are you using flux, redux, reflux.. etc ? they are simply the means of how to do this. you can import pushstate from react router... and push state will update your page and push a new state onto it. react router will then re route you to where you are trying to go. you need to dispatch it if you are using a framework like flux... etc